# Write a program that finds the largest element in a list of numbers and switches index position with the last element

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list = [5,23,6,1,8]
max_num = max(my_list)
max_num,  my_list[-1] = my_list[-1], max_num
my_list
my_list.insert(1,8)
my_list.remove(23)
my_list
```

My code works this way but essentially I'm asking if there's an easier way to write this or a way to write it that works universally for all lists so that I don't need to amend the code based on the numbers in the list or length of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
my_list = [5, 23, 6, 1, 8]
max_num = max(my_list)
max_num_idx = my_list.index(max_num)
my_list[max_num_idx], my_list[-1] = my_list[-1], my_list[max_num_idx]
```